# Fragmentのタッチイベントを取得する方法を教えて下さい。

Tags: android, android-fragments

Fragmentのタッチイベントを取得する方法を教えて下さい。

詳細：
　お世話になっております。
　現在、Fragmentに設置した「WebViewの履歴の有無」で「バックボタン」を指定のデザインで表示できる動作を実装しております。
　　「WebViewの履歴の無」→「バックボタン」非表示
　　「WebViewの履歴の有」→「バックボタン」表示

表示動作は完成しております。
　次に、この動作を「画面をタッチするごとに履歴の有無を判定」することで行おうと思っていたのですが、ここで難航しております。

画面タッチイベントを取得したいのですが、Fragmentのタッチイベントはどのように実装するのでしょうか？

以下のサイトやその他を参考に試したのですが取得出来ておりません。
　http://d.hatena.ne.jp/tetsu831/20111017/1318833874
　コード上でエラーが発生していないため、何が問題なのか検討もつかない状況です。

ご存知の方がおられましたらアドバイスをいただけないでしょうか？
　よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: バックボタンはWebView内に設置されているのでしょうか。
どのような実装かわからないのでアドバイスが難しいと思います。

Comment: 返信が遅くなり申し訳ありません。本件、自己解決することができました。ご迷惑をお掛けいたしました。原因はレイアウトにあり、scrollView-LinearLayout_webviewの構成が邪魔をしていたようです。webv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {}でタッチイベントを習得する方法を採用いたしました。失礼いたしました。